# Rasterizing circle to exact size

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, raster

I have created a circle in Illustrator with a radius of `12px`.

[image]

Now I'm trying to rasterize this into a `.png` from Photoshop to have the exact same size, but anti-aliasing is messing things up and the height is actually `11px` instead of `12px`.

[image]

I tried both, exporting the `.png` from AI and opening the `.ai` file from Photoshop but I get the same result.  So how can I rasterize my vector to match the desired size?

Comment: Is this for a website?

Comment: nope, for iOS game and I would like to get images as precise as possible, because on Retina display you can notice problems.

Comment: If you are looking for accuracy why are you not coding it instead of using images?

Comment: a) Drawing from sprite is cheaper b) Circle is not the only shape I am interested in, but presented as an example to find common solution. Of course it's much easier to draw shapes in vector designing SW rather than code it.

Comment: What happens when you set the center point (x,y origins) of the object to integers?

Comment: @horatio: magic happens and I got all pixel-precisely converted :) Any way to tell AI always use integer pixels?

Comment: @horatio I'd post that as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your shape is placed on whole pixel values (ie, X:851px and not X:851,728 px)
If your object is aligned to the pixel grid, antialiasing won't make it bigger.

You can do this easily by selecting the option "Align to pixel grid" in the Transform panel (if you don't see it, select "show options" from the flyout menu)

[image: Align to pixel grid]

To do this automatically for new objects, in the transform panel options choose "Align new objects to pixel grid"

[image]

Comment: brilliant. for existing objects I have to do it manually, right?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Fireworks is ideal for stuff like this. You can create, align, scale, resize vector graphics pixel perfect, and export them as numerous formats, including PNG.

You can even define where the color edge is drawn, inside vector shape, in the middle of the vector shape path, or on the outside.

Comment: Can I still use my AI files in Fireworks or I have to draw new vectors?

Comment: You can open AI files with Fireworks without problems as well as you can save your Fireworks PNG files back as AI.

Answer (score 0):

I ask now rhetorically: "What happens when you set the center point (x,y origins) of the object to integers?"

When the origin is set as a fraction of a pixel, when the object is rasterized, there will be rounding of fractions (probably down to the nearest integer).

In my humble opinion, AI should not allow you to specify fractions of pixels, but there it is.

Comment: In iOS coding pixels also using floating point units for some reason.

Comment: I guess one cannot know a pixel's size and position at the same time any more...